# how can I understand there is specific value before X value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

it s complex to explain. I give example

### data

```
id  value
-- -------
1    61
2    50
3     A
4    61
5   750
6    61
7    20
8     A
```

### result expected

```
id  value  code
--  -----  ----
1      61      A
4      61  OTHER 
6      61      A
```

how it should be like that :

I want to select rows which value is **61**

if belong two value 61 has a **'A'** so the **code** value is `'A'` if not the result is **'OTHER'** how can I do that with one select statement.

**EDIT:**

**The logic**:

If the `value` 61 exists, and if any of the preceding columns contain `A` then the column `code` should write `A`, otherwise `OTHER`. In the given data example:

```
id  value
-- -------
1    61
2    50
3     A
```

id 1, has value 61, and it's preceding values (until the next 61) contains an A so it should print:

```
id  value  code
--  -----  ----
1      61      A
```

However the next 61 and it's preceding rows do not:

```
4    61
5   750
```

so it should print:

```
4   61  OTHER
```

thanks in advance

Comment: this isn't really clear. What's the logic behind the `OTHER` code?

Comment: What do you mean by "if belong two value 61 has a 'A' so the code value is 'A' if not the result is 'OTHER' how can I do that with one select statement."?

Comment: Can you get a native english speaker to help you re-write your question?   It's not making much sense as written.   However, I suspect the answer to your question is the `LAG()` function.

Comment: **what reason?**

Comment: I think he's saying if the value 61 exists, if the any of the preceding values until the next 61 are A then Column code should be `A`, otherwise `OTHER`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### finally I found solution

```
WITH SUBQ AS
(
SELECT 1 AS id,'61' AS value UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   '50' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,   'A'  UNION ALL
SELECT 4,   '61'  UNION ALL
SELECT 5,   '750'  UNION ALL
SELECT 6,   '61'  UNION ALL
SELECT 7,   '20'  UNION ALL
SELECT 8,   'A'
),
SUBQ2 AS
(
SELECT 
 id,
 value
FROM SUBQ
WHERE value IN ('A')
),
SUBQ3 AS
(
SELECT 
 id,
 value,
 LEAD(id,1,999999999)OVER(ORDER BY id) AS NEXT_GKEY
FROM SUBQ
  WHERE value = '61'
),
SUBQ4 AS
(
SELECT
 SUBQ3.id,
 SUBQ2.value
FROM SUBQ3 
INNER JOIN SUBQ2 ON SUBQ2.id BETWEEN SUBQ3.id AND SUBQ3.NEXT_GKEY
),
SUBQ5 AS
(
SELECT id
FROM SUBQ3
WHERE id NOT IN
(
SELECT id FROM  SUBQ4
)
),
SUBQ6 AS
(
SELECT 
id ,
'OTHER' AS REASON
FROM SUBQ5
UNION 
SELECT 
id,
CAST(value AS VARCHAR(100)) AS REASON
FROM SUBQ4
)
SELECT * FROM SUBQ6 ORDER BY id
```

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmmmmm

Comment: ? what is hmmmm

Comment: hmm is at least some response

Answer (score 0):

You may use an outer self-join to solve it.

```
select t.id, t.value, case when t.rn = 1 and t.cnt > 0 then 'A' else 'OTHER' end code
from
(
  select d1.*, 
         row_number() over (partition by d1.value, count(d2.id) order by d1.id desc) rn,
         count(d2.id) cnt
  from data d1
  left join data d2 on d1.id < d2.id and d2.value = 'A'
  group   by d1.id, d1.value
) t
where t.value = '61'
order by t.id
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c573b54272229909c56e57ebda993b9f)

`cnt` column is used to solve the last '61' occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    create table #MyTable(id int, value varchar(10))
    insert into #MyTable values(1,'61')
    insert into #MyTable values(2,'50')
    insert into #MyTable values(3,'A')
    insert into #MyTable values(4,'61')
    insert into #MyTable values(5,'750')
    insert into #MyTable values(6,'61')
    insert into #MyTable values(7,'20')
    insert into #MyTable values(8,'A')
    --insert into #MyTable values(9,'61')



    --Select * from #MyTable

    Select ROW_Number() over(order by id) as rn, * 
    into #tmp1  
    from #MyTable where value='61'


    SELECT t1.id,t1.value
        ,CASE WHEN MAX(t.value) ='A' THEN 'A'
        ELSE 'OTHER' END AS COde
    FROM #MyTable t
    JOIN #tmp1 t1 on t1.id<t.id
    JOIN #tmp1 t2 on (t1.rn=t2.rn-1 and t.id<t2.id)
    Group by t1.id,t1.value

    UNION


    /*For Last Row with 61*/
    SELECT t1.id,t1.value
        ,CASE WHEN MAX(t.value) ='A' THEN 'A'
        ELSE 'OTHER' END AS COde FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 1 * from #tmp1 order by rn desc) t1 
    JOIN #MyTable t on t.id>=t1.id
    Group by t1.id,t1.value


    Drop table #MyTable

    Drop table #tmp1
```